# python: remove records from a dataset comparing two histograms

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, histogram

I have two many columns (order 10) datasets with different lengths (each row is a record), that have to become the same number of rows: the criterion is a **binning over a number of columns, from 2 to 4**, and then remove the exceeding records in one of the two dataset (picking randomly between all the records in that bin).

I'm currently using *numpy*, but it would be fine to use *pandas* as well.

Since I know in advance one dataset is smaller than the other My (naive let me say) idea is to compute the two histograms (smaller first), subtract one from the other to have the differences in each bin, the walk the datasets to remove the exceeding records, BUT: I have to know what record is in what bin!!

A code snippet to compute histograms in `python` (two columns dataset for the sake of simplicity):

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as rd
x = 50*rd.random((100, 5))
np.histogram2d(x[:, 0], x[:, 1], bins=[10, 5])
```

Is there a way to keep track of dataset indexes when binning?
I know `pandas` data frames can have indexes, so they could be a natural choice, provided **I stick with this algorithm**.

Is there a more clever way to do this, changing algorithm but sticking with python?

Comment: does [numpy.digitize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice solution using `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
x = 50 * np.random.randn(50, 5)
dfx = pd.DataFrame(x)
bins = np.linspace(min(dfx[0]), max(dfx[0]), 10)
first_binning = pd.cut(dfx[0], bins)
bins = np.linspace(min(dfx[1]), max(dfx[1]), 5)
second_binning = pd.cut(ddx[1], bins)
groups = dfx.groupby([first_binning, second_binning])
```

and now you can make (depending on your data):

```
In [160]: groups.size()
Out[160]:
0                    1
(-101.273, -71.403]  (50.481, 109.902]      2
(-71.403, -41.532]   (-68.362, -8.94]       4
                     (-8.94, 50.481]        3
                     (50.481, 109.902]      1
(-41.532, -11.661]   (-68.362, -8.94]       4
                     (-8.94, 50.481]        3
                     (50.481, 109.902]      2
(-11.661, 18.21]     (-127.783, -68.362]    2
                     (-8.94, 50.481]        6
                     (50.481, 109.902]      1
(18.21, 48.0806]     (-127.783, -68.362]    2
                     (-68.362, -8.94]       5
                     (-8.94, 50.481]        3
                     (50.481, 109.902]      3
(48.0806, 77.951]    (-68.362, -8.94]       2
                     (-8.94, 50.481]        4
(77.951, 107.822]    (-68.362, -8.94]       1
dtype: int64
```

to see counts, and

```
In [163]: groups.indices
Out[163]:
{('(-101.273, -71.403]', '(50.481, 109.902]'): array([20, 37]),
 ('(-11.661, 18.21]', '(-127.783, -68.362]'): array([26, 39]),
 ('(-11.661, 18.21]', '(-8.94, 50.481]'): array([ 4, 14, 18, 34, 35,     45]),
 ('(-11.661, 18.21]', '(50.481, 109.902]'): array([17]),
 ('(-41.532, -11.661]', '(-68.362, -8.94]'): array([ 3, 13, 16, 30]),
 ('(-41.532, -11.661]', '(-8.94, 50.481]'): array([25, 38, 48]),
 ('(-41.532, -11.661]', '(50.481, 109.902]'): array([0, 5]),
 ('(-71.403, -41.532]', '(-68.362, -8.94]'): array([ 1, 24, 32, 47]),
 ('(-71.403, -41.532]', '(-8.94, 50.481]'): array([ 6, 19, 31]),
 ('(-71.403, -41.532]', '(50.481, 109.902]'): array([12]),
 ('(18.21, 48.0806]', '(-127.783, -68.362]'): array([21, 46]),
 ('(18.21, 48.0806]', '(-68.362, -8.94]'): array([ 2, 15, 22, 33, 40]),
 ('(18.21, 48.0806]', '(-8.94, 50.481]'): array([ 7, 28, 36]),
 ('(18.21, 48.0806]', '(50.481, 109.902]'): array([ 9, 23, 49]),
 ('(48.0806, 77.951]', '(-68.362, -8.94]'): array([41, 42]),
 ('(48.0806, 77.951]', '(-8.94, 50.481]'): array([27, 29, 43, 44]),
 ('(77.951, 107.822]', '(-68.362, -8.94]'): array([11])}
```

to see dataset record indices of course.